# pdf.js with local pdf file

Tags: html, pdf, pdf.js

I'm trying out the pdf.js library and just want to display a local pdf file on my server instead of the pdf file provided by the example.

```
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>

  <!-- Use latest PDF.js build from Github -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //
    // NOTE:
    // Modifying the URL below to another server will likely *NOT* work. Because of browser
    // security restrictions, we have to use a file server with special headers
    // (CORS) - most servers don't support cross-origin browser requests.
    //
    var url = '/test.pdf';

    //
    // Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers need the URL of
    // the script to be loaded, and dynamically loading a cross-origin script does
    // not work)
    //
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    //
    // Asynchronous download PDF as an ArrayBuffer
    //
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
      //
      // Fetch the first page
      //
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        //
        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        //
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        //
        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        //
        page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I changed there pdf url to my local '/test.pdf' url. However this gives me the message it cannot find the file when it's clearly there in my root folder. Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: did you find the answer ?

Comment: Working on too - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541680/is-it-possible-to-convert-local-pdf-to-html-2b-improved-using-pdf-js

Answer (score 1):

modify pdfjs/web/viewer.js file and change the

```
var DEFAULT_URL = '<file path on your server>'
```

This worked when I tried to implement the demo at http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html on my local system

Comment: Could you load from a file path in local directory? I know they disable this for security purpose but i need to read from specific file path