# what should be the parameters to calling webmethod while uploading file using fileupload control?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to open pdf file in new window as soon as it is selected from fileupload control (without upload)i want to view the selected file in new window before uploading it . I tried so much but i am not able to getting filepath since it is not uploaded. please, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview .doc/.docx/.pdf files before uploading to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344636/preview-doc-docx-pdf-files-before-uploading-to-server)

Comment: Thank you for your help. i got my solution .